# To show that a function is a random variable, how can one show that it holds for all Borel sets?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

In probability theory a random variable is defined to be a measurable function $X$ from $\Omega$ into $\mathbb{R}$, where "measurable" means that the preimage $X^{-1}(B) = \{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \in B\}$ is in $\mathcal{F}$ for all Borel sets $B$. Hence, it appears to me that in order to check that a random variable is indeed a random variable, it suffices to check this condition.

In the trivial case where $X = \mathbb{1}_{A}$ is the indicator of some event $A \in \mathcal{F}$, then we can show that $X$ is a random variable by observing that if  $X = \mathbb{1}_{A}$ for $A \in \mathcal{F}$, then $X^{-1}(B)$ is either in $A$, or not in $A$. If it is in $A$, then we have $A$. If it's not, then it can either be in $A^C$, $\emptyset$, $\Omega$. But, $A, A^C, \emptyset, \Omega$ yield a $\sigma$-algebra so $X^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{F}$.

It seems that for the trivial case, we had to list that it worked for all Borel sets, but that because the Borel sets here were trivial, it was easy. In the general case, how can we show that it works for all Borel sets? From my understanding the Borel sets are incredibly complicated so how would one show that it works for every possible ordering? Or am I misunderstanding something here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice two-step procedure:

Step 1. Show that $X^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal F$ for all $B$ in a convenient $\pi$-system of subsets of $\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$.  (A $\pi$-system is a class of sets closed under pairwise intersections.) Sample $\pi$-systems: open sets, open intervals, half-lines $(-\infty,b]$, etc.

Step 2. Appeal to a general result (a form of the Monotone Class Theorem) stating that if $X^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal F$ for all $B$ in a $\pi$-system $\mathcal C$ (of subsets of $\Bbb R$) then $X^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal F$ for all $B$ in $\sigma(\mathcal C)$ (the sigma-algebra generated by $\mathcal C$).

Answer (score 1):

$X^{-1}(B) = \{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \in B\}\in\mathcal{F}$ is equivalent to $\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) <x, \:x\in \Bbb{R}\}\in\mathcal{F}$, which means that $X$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}$. The latter is often used to decide if $X$ is measurable for its simplicity.

Comment: The formula  $\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) <x, \:x\in \Bbb{R}\}$ should be modified.